# How can i retrive from database using API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

So i have my problem with API to get 'status' from database. the condition is when status is null the response must give a string, "Kendaraan belum terparkir" here's my API

```
public function riwayatParkir() {
        try {
            $data = DB::table('dataparkirs')->where('no_kartu', Auth::User()->no_kartu)->get();
            $status = DB::table('parkirs')
            ->select('parkirs.status')
            ->where('no_kartu', Auth::User()->no_kartu)
            ->get();

            if (count($status) < 1) {
                return response()->json(['error'=>false,'Status Kendaraan belum terparkir'=>$status], 200);
            } else {

            return response()->json(['error'=>false,'Data'=>$data, 'Status Kendaraan'=>$status], 200);
          }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return SendResponse::fails($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

i have try with Postman, but the result status is []
[result postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v069f.png)

Comment: ```$status``` is not null. Check the status like this: ```if(!count($status))``` to check its null or no

Answer (score 0):

From the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table) documentation:

> The get method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance
> containing the results of the query where each result is an instance
> of the PHP stdClass object.

So the `$status` in your case never will be `null`. You should check [size of collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-count) instead of.

```php
            if ($status->count() === 0) {
                return response()->json(['error'=>false,'Status Kendaraan belum terparkir'=>$status], 200);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `NULL` use `count()`

```
if (count($status) < 1) {
  return response()->json(['error'=>false,'status' => 'Status Kendaraan belum terparkir'], 200);
}
```

Comment: great it works! the `$status` now is null, but how can i get return the response json with string? like this `$status = "Status Kendaraan belum terparkir"`